# Approximate $f(1.01)$ for a function satisfying $f'(x) = 3f(x) + 3x$ and $f(1)=3$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Suppose that the derivative of a function satisfies the formula $f'(x) = 3f(x) + 3x$. If  $f(1)=3$, use linear approximation to estimate the value of the function at $1.01$.

I think I found 
$f(x) = 3x$.

I do not need the answer (you can still provide it if you want), I just need to know how to do this. I kept reading my book but I do not know what steps to take to tackle this questions. Maybe someone is able to explain to me clearly.

Comment: I thought f(1.01) = 3(1.03) would get me the answer
Since how I got f(x) = 3x is by comparing 
y'= f(x+x')-f(x)

Answer (score 3):

Linear approximation is nothing more then the tangent line to the graph, that is: $$f(x) \approx f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0).$$

Other way of writing this is: $$f(x_0+h) \approx f(x_0) + f'(x_0) \cdot h.$$

The issue here is the following: you don't have an explicit expression for $f$, so, a priori, we can't find a general expression for $f'(x)$. Then comes in the relation that you were given: $$f'(x) = 3f(x)+3x.$$

We can solve the *differential equation* to find the expression for $f$, but let's leave that for another day. Evaluating the relation given at $1$, we have: $$f'(1) = 3f(1) + 3\cdot 1 = 12.$$

This way: $$f(1.01) \approx f(1)+f'(1) \cdot 0.01 = 3+12\cdot 0.01 = 3.12.$$

Ok?

Comment: Trying to imagine how the first two equations relate. But I think that make sense.

Comment: Call $x - x_0 = h$. Then $x = x_0 + h$.

Comment: Ahh I see it now. Thanks!

Comment: Don't mind it. Glad to help (:

Comment: Is there anything else we can help you with? If the problem is solved, you can accept one of the answers (checkmark at the left of the answer). This way the question goes out of the unanswered list, and the site flows better (:

Answer (score 1):

Use the Taylor approximation:

$$f(a+h)\approx f(a)+f'(a)h$$
for $a=1$ and $h=0.01$. In your case, $f'(1)$ can be expressed with your formula:
$$f(1+h)\approx f(1)+(3f(1)+3\cdot 1)h$$
you have everything you need, just plug it in.

So, they don't actually expect you to solve the differential equation. But you can, it's a simple linear differential equation with constant coefficient. The general solution is

$$f(x)=Ce^{3x}-x-\frac13$$
for arbitrary $C$. From the condition $f(1)=3$ you get $C=13/(3e)$. However, as I said, they don't expect you to do this.

Comment: And using this rigorous solution, we should find that $f(1.01)=3.12197$. So, let us admire the beauty of the linear approximation !